# How can I iterate through SQL results like a for loop and an array?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table, and I want to select only the single column of row IDs from it, but in a specific order.  Then, I want to loop through that column like below:

```
for (i=0; i<rows.length; i++)
{
  if(i==rows.length-1)
    UPDATE myTable SET nextID = NULL WHERE ID = rows[i]
  ELSE
    UPDATE myTable SET nextID = rows[i+1] WHERE ID = rows[i]
}
```

I just dont know how to access the results of my select statement with an index like that.  Is there a way of doing this in sql server?

Comment: You want **[CURSOR](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180169.aspx)**, but I strongly suggest to reconsider it and find solution which is SET based, not ROW based. Looping each row (CURSOR) is weapon of last resort, when everything else fails.

Comment: Performing `update` inside a loop is probably the wrong approach.  You just want to write a single, good `update` statement.  If you show the `select` statement that fetches the rows you want to update, you'll be able to ensure you get an accurate answer.

Comment: What language is this? It looks like PHP? Please tag appropriately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you didn't provide many details, let's pretend your table looks something like this:

```
create table MyTable (
  Id int not null primary key,
  Name varchar(50) not null,
  NextId int
)
```

> I want to select only the single column of row IDs from it, ***but in a specific order***

Let's just say that in this case, you decide to order the rows alphabetically by `Name`.  So let's pretend that the `select` statement that you want to loop through looks like this:

```
select Id
  from MyTable
 order by Name
```

That being the case, instead of looping through the rows and attempting to update each row using the pseudo-code you provided, you can replace the whole thing with a single `update` statement that will perform the exact same work:

```
with cte as (
  select *,
         NewNextId = lead(Id) over (order by Name)
    from MyTable
)
update cte
   set NextId = NewNextId
```

Just make sure to adjust the `order by` clause to whatever your *specific order* really is.  I just used `Name` in my example, but it might be something else in your case.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a cursor, or you could use something a bit smarter.

Your example should be able to be written fairly easily along the lines of:

```
update mytable set nextID = LEAD(id,1) over (order by id)
```

Lead(id,1) will grab the next id, 1 row ahead in the record set and update the nextID field with it. If it can't find one it will return null. No looping or conditional logic needed!

edit: I forgot the over clause. This is the part that tells it how you would like it ordered for the lead

Comment: just a note lead only applies to sql 2014 and above.

Comment: Ah, good point. 2012 should work also though: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213125(v=sql.110).aspx